Why provisioning script is not making file creation/edition to persist
I'm using packer to create a qcow2 disk image from scratch with a base alpine iso using the qemu builder and provisioning it.
The boot_command executes setup-alpine command from alpine to set network and disks.
But when the shell provisioner script run, apparently it is executed correctly, but changes made with the script are not in the final disk image.
im using the alpine virtual iso image downloaded from:
dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.20/releases/x86_64/alpine-virt-3.20.3-x86_64.iso
alpine.pkr.hcl:
packer {
  required_plugins {
    qemu = {
      version = ">= 1.0.10"
      source  = "github.com/hashicorp/qemu"
    }
  }
}

source "qemu" "alpine-demo" {
  iso_url           = "./alpine-virt-3.20.3-x86_64.iso"
  iso_checksum      = "81df854fbd7327d293c726b1eeeb82061d3bc8f5a86a6f77eea720f6be372261"
  output_directory  = "build"
  disk_image        = false
  disk_size         = "5000M"
  disk_interface    = "virtio"
  format            = "qcow2"
  accelerator       = "kvm"
  vm_name           = "alpine-minimal.qcow2"
  machine_type      = "pc"
  net_device        = "virtio-net"
  headless          = false
  cpus              = 1
  boot_key_interval = "10ms"
  shutdown_command  = "poweroff"
  communicator      = "ssh"
  ssh_username      = "root"
  ssh_password      = "alpine"
  ssh_timeout       = "10m"
  memory            = "1024"
  boot_wait         = "10s"
  boot_command = [
    "<wait>root<enter><wait>",
    "setup-alpine<enter><wait>",
    "us<enter>us<enter><wait>",
    "<enter><wait><enter><wait><enter><wait><enter><wait5>",
    "alpine<enter><wait>alpine<enter><wait>",
    "<enter><wait5>",
    "<enter><wait><enter><wait><enter><wait><enter><wait>",
    "yes<enter><wait>",
    "<enter><wait5>",
    "vda<enter><wait>sys<enter><wait>y<enter><wait20>",
  ]
}

build {
  name    = "learn-packer"
  sources = ["source.qemu.alpine-demo"]
  provisioner "shell" {
    script = "./provisioner.sh"
  }
}


provisioner.sh
#!/bin/sh

set -ex

touch createdfile
echo "JAJAJ" > createdfile

if [ -f ./createdfile ]; then
    echo "good"
else
    echo "bad"
fi

PACKER_LOG=1 packer build ./alpine.pkr.hcl


relevant logs:
==> learn-packer.qemu.alpine-demo: Provisioning with shell script: ./provisioner.sh
2024/10/25 18:35:10 packer-provisioner-shell plugin: Opening ./provisioner.sh for reading
2024/10/25 18:35:10 packer-plugin-qemu_v1.1.0_x5.0_linux_amd64 plugin: 2024/10/25 18:35:10 [DEBUG] Opening new ssh session
2024/10/25 18:35:10 packer-provisioner-shell plugin: [INFO] 470 bytes written for 'uploadData'
2024/10/25 18:35:10 [INFO] 470 bytes written for 'uploadData'
2024/10/25 18:35:10 packer-plugin-qemu_v1.1.0_x5.0_linux_amd64 plugin: 2024/10/25 18:35:10 [DEBUG] Starting remote scp process:  scp -vt /tmp
2024/10/25 18:35:10 packer-plugin-qemu_v1.1.0_x5.0_linux_amd64 plugin: 2024/10/25 18:35:10 [DEBUG] Started SCP session, beginning transfers...
2024/10/25 18:35:10 packer-plugin-qemu_v1.1.0_x5.0_linux_amd64 plugin: 2024/10/25 18:35:10 [DEBUG] Copying input data into temporary file so we can read the length
2024/10/25 18:35:10 packer-plugin-qemu_v1.1.0_x5.0_linux_amd64 plugin: 2024/10/25 18:35:10 [DEBUG] scp: Uploading script_2897.sh: perms=C0644 size=470
2024/10/25 18:35:10 packer-plugin-qemu_v1.1.0_x5.0_linux_amd64 plugin: 2024/10/25 18:35:10 [DEBUG] SCP session complete, closing stdin pipe.
2024/10/25 18:35:10 packer-plugin-qemu_v1.1.0_x5.0_linux_amd64 plugin: 2024/10/25 18:35:10 [DEBUG] Waiting for SSH session to complete.
2024/10/25 18:35:10 packer-plugin-qemu_v1.1.0_x5.0_linux_amd64 plugin: 2024/10/25 18:35:10 [DEBUG] scp stderr (length 70): Sink: C0644 470 script_2897.sh
2024/10/25 18:35:10 packer-plugin-qemu_v1.1.0_x5.0_linux_amd64 plugin: scp: debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
2024/10/25 18:35:10 packer-plugin-qemu_v1.1.0_x5.0_linux_amd64 plugin: 2024/10/25 18:35:10 [DEBUG] Opening new ssh session
2024/10/25 18:35:10 packer-plugin-qemu_v1.1.0_x5.0_linux_amd64 plugin: 2024/10/25 18:35:10 [DEBUG] starting remote command: chmod 0755 /tmp/script_2897.sh
2024/10/25 18:35:10 packer-plugin-qemu_v1.1.0_x5.0_linux_amd64 plugin: 2024/10/25 18:35:10 [INFO] RPC endpoint: Communicator ended with: 0
2024/10/25 18:35:10 [INFO] RPC client: Communicator ended with: 0
2024/10/25 18:35:10 [INFO] RPC endpoint: Communicator ended with: 0
2024/10/25 18:35:10 packer-provisioner-shell plugin: [INFO] RPC client: Communicator ended with: 0
2024/10/25 18:35:10 packer-plugin-qemu_v1.1.0_x5.0_linux_amd64 plugin: 2024/10/25 18:35:10 [DEBUG] Opening new ssh session
2024/10/25 18:35:10 packer-plugin-qemu_v1.1.0_x5.0_linux_amd64 plugin: 2024/10/25 18:35:10 [DEBUG] starting remote command: chmod +x /tmp/script_2897.sh; PACKER_BUILDER_TYPE='qemu' PACKER_BUILD_NAME='alpine-demo' PACKER_HTTP_ADDR='10.0.2.2:0' PACKER_HTTP_IP='10.0.2.2' PACKER_HTTP_PORT='0'  /tmp/script_2897.sh
2024/10/25 18:35:10 packer-plugin-qemu_v1.1.0_x5.0_linux_amd64 plugin: 2024/10/25 18:35:10 [INFO] RPC endpoint: Communicator ended with: 0
2024/10/25 18:35:10 [INFO] 5 bytes written for 'stdout'
2024/10/25 18:35:10 [INFO] 70 bytes written for 'stderr'
2024/10/25 18:35:10 [INFO] RPC client: Communicator ended with: 0
2024/10/25 18:35:10 [INFO] RPC endpoint: Communicator ended with: 0
2024/10/25 18:35:10 packer-provisioner-shell plugin: [INFO] 70 bytes written for 'stderr'
2024/10/25 18:35:10 packer-provisioner-shell plugin: [INFO] 5 bytes written for 'stdout'
    learn-packer.qemu.alpine-demo: good
2024/10/25 18:35:10 packer-provisioner-shell plugin: [INFO] RPC client: Communicator ended with: 0
==> learn-packer.qemu.alpine-demo: + touch createdfile
==> learn-packer.qemu.alpine-demo: + echo JAJAJ
==> learn-packer.qemu.alpine-demo: + '[' -f ./createdfile ]
==> learn-packer.qemu.alpine-demo: + echo good
2024/10/25 18:35:10 packer-plugin-qemu_v1.1.0_x5.0_linux_amd64 plugin: 2024/10/25 18:35:10 [DEBUG] Opening new ssh session
2024/10/25 18:35:10 packer-plugin-qemu_v1.1.0_x5.0_linux_amd64 plugin: 2024/10/25 18:35:10 [DEBUG] starting remote command: rm -f /tmp/script_2897.sh
2024/10/25 18:35:10 packer-plugin-qemu_v1.1.0_x5.0_linux_amd64 plugin: 2024/10/25 18:35:10 [INFO] RPC endpoint: Communicator ended with: 0
2024/10/25 18:35:10 [INFO] RPC client: Communicator ended with: 0
2024/10/25 18:35:10 [INFO] RPC endpoint: Communicator ended with: 0
2024/10/25 18:35:10 packer-provisioner-shell plugin: [INFO] RPC client: Communicator ended with: 0
2024/10/25 18:35:10 packer-plugin-qemu_v1.1.0_x5.0_linux_amd64 plugin: 2024/10/25 18:35:10 [DEBUG] Opening new ssh session
2024/10/25 18:35:10 packer-plugin-qemu_v1.1.0_x5.0_linux_amd64 plugin: 2024/10/25 18:35:10 [DEBUG] starting remote command: rm -f
2024/10/25 18:35:10 packer-plugin-qemu_v1.1.0_x5.0_linux_amd64 plugin: 2024/10/25 18:35:10 [INFO] RPC endpoint: Communicator ended with: 0
2024/10/25 18:35:10 [INFO] RPC client: Communicator ended with: 0
2024/10/25 18:35:10 [INFO] RPC endpoint: Communicator ended with: 0
2024/10/25 18:35:10 packer-provisioner-shell plugin: [INFO] RPC client: Communicator ended with: 0
2024/10/25 18:35:10 [INFO] (telemetry) ending shell
2024/10/25 18:35:10 packer-plugin-qemu_v1.1.0_x5.0_linux_amd64 plugin: 2024/10/25 18:35:10 Executing shutdown command: echo 'packer' | poweroff
2024/10/25 18:35:10 packer-plugin-qemu_v1.1.0_x5.0_linux_amd64 plugin: 2024/10/25 18:35:10 [DEBUG] Opening new ssh session
==> learn-packer.qemu.alpine-demo: Gracefully halting virtual machine...

runs the vm:
qemu-system-x86_64 -name alpinelinux3.19-minimal \
                   -machine type=pc,accel=kvm \
                   -cpu host \
                   -m 512M \
                   -enable-kvm \
                   -nic user \
                   -drive file=./build/alpine-minimal.qcow2,if=virtio,media=disk \
                   -boot c

when logged as root on vm, the file createdfile doesn't exist, even if i edit configs in /etc/
I don't know what I'm missing
